# Convert date string to ISO format issue mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am joining two tables together by employee name. I have that part working. The issue that I have currently is that I need the date and time to be ISO format and I need to do that within my aggregation. I cant figure out how.

I need to convert:

```
2018-11-03:10:47:31
```

To:

```
2018-11-03T10:47:31.000Z
```

employee collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "name": "Test"
}
```

clock collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "employeeName": "Test",
    "time": "2014-11-21:17:15:00"
}
```

Here is my join

```
dbo.collection("employee").aggregate([
{ "$lookup": {
    "localField": "name",
    "from": "clock",
    "foreignField": "clock.employeeName",
    "as": "employeeInfo"
}
}]).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: What is your mongoDB version?

Comment: I am using mongo 3.6

Comment: Is this an existing app with existing data?  If not, why don't you store the data in the proper format?  If so, how expensive would it be to convert the data to the proper format?

Comment: @c1moore its an existing application and I cannot properly format in the database itself

Comment: Why can't you do this in the database itself?  And why does this have to be part of the aggregation?

Comment: @c1moore its a huge effort as its part of an existing application

Comment: The problem is that your date format is weird and you could do this with `$dateFromString` but its `format` option is only available in mongoDB 4.0 and up.

Comment: @Akrion yes we can do that.

Comment: OK then simply look into either doing something like `$unwind` and then `$addFields` where inside you would do something like `"employeeInfo.date": { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$employeeInfo.time", format: "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S" } }`. I do not have 4.0 handy right now to give you the full query.

Comment: The idea is to use the `format` option of `$dateFromString` since your date format is completely messed up and mongoDB does not recognize it by default nor when you pass it to `new Date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date is in very weird format `2018-11-03:10:47:31` you can't easily parse it with mongo prior version 4.0. The reason for this is that in 4.0 the **`format`** option was added to the [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) function which allows you to specify random date format which to parse with. So as you mention if 4.0 is an option then you would do something like this:

Adding a field to your aggregation after you unwind the `employeeInfo`:

```
$addFields: {
  "employeeInfo.date": {
    $dateFromString: {
      dateString: "$employeeInfo.time",
      format: "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S"
    }
  }
}
```

Or projecting it in your project pipeline.

```
{
    "$project": {
      "employeeInfo.time": {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$employeeInfo.time",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The project approach might need the `unwind` before hand as well since it might be picky on the fact that you have an array as `employeeInfo`

Comment: Could you pls help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version