# MongoDB: how to parse date in 3.6 mongoDb version?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have created [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6jZlHzjuQAm) here

Current output is showing result based on 15min time interval. (grouping updatedAt value by 15mins and shows avg for some field)

Currently $dateToString and $dateFromString is using format to parse the date. 
I need to make it work for mongo version 3.6 (3.6 is not supporting format for $dateFromString)

```
 parsedDate: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$_id.dateHour",
                format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H"
              }
            }
```

If I remove format field from both $dateToString and $dateFromString, query still runs but output for "dateHour" shows different value than expected. (as below)

```
"dateHour": ISODate("2020-03-20T18:46:50Z"),
```

format field is not supported in 3.6. Have to make this query compatible for 3.6 version.
Final output has no change.

Main focus is to get "dateHour" value same after this change.

Current output :

```
"dateHour": ISODate("2020-03-19T18:30:00Z"),
```

expected output:

```
"dateHour": ISODate("2020-03-19T18:30:00Z"),
```

Comment: well, what is the difference between the current and expected outputs?, they are the same

Comment: no difference. output should remain same but query should be for 3.6.. current query uses format field in dateFromString operator which is not supported in Mongod v 3.6

Comment: Bumping to get some help

Answer (score 2):

Use [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) and its counterpart [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)

Here is an updated [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eeM5ZSfiDGU)

What it does is basically break the date into its parts:

```js
{
  $project: {
    dateHour: {
      $dateToParts: {
        date: "$updatedAt"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

would produce:

```json
{
  "dateHour": {
    "day": 19,
    "hour": 18,
    "millisecond": 0,
    "minute": 21,
    "month": 3,
    "second": 5,
    "year": 2020
  }
}
```

and then later you reconstruct the date from its parts:

```js
{
  $project: {
    reconstructedDateHour: {
      $dateFromParts: {
        year: "$dateHour.year",
        month: "$dateHour.month",
        day: "$dateHour.day",
        hour: "$dateHour.hour"
      }
    }
  }
}
```