# MongoDb: Convert date string to specific format in mongodb 3.6

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to parse date value to specific format without using format field in dateFromString operator.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U9thsJCE88V)

Current situation : 
in Mongodb 4.0 if I format dateString using below it code it give me mentioned output.

```
 parsedDate: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$dateS",
          format: format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H"
        }
      }
Output: "parsedDate": ISODate("2020-01-16T08:00:00Z")
```

I cannot use format field in 3.6 since its not supported.
How do I convert my date to
 `format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H"` in 3.6?

Comment: From what I gather, you want a date `ISODate("2020-01-16T08:00:00Z")` to be converted to this --> `"2020-01-16T08"` in mongodb version 3.6 correct?

Comment: to be converted to this ---- > 2020-03-20T18:00:00Z

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: how to parse date in 3.6 mongoDb version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version)

Comment: In the previous comment your expected op is March date `2020-03-20T18:00:00Z` from and Januray one `2020-01-16T08:00:00Z`. Might be a typo

Comment: @Valijon actually thats my question from yesterday and nobody was interested so I posted back with less details and less confusion.

Comment: @ambianBeing yes its a typo. sorry about that

Comment: You shouldn't post several times the same question, think about in update your question (provide sample, expectation, etc...) and/or offer a bounty

Comment: I agree with @Valijon. Ideally one could add more clarity and details to the quesion as an update to increase the visibility from the community and subsequently resort to a small bounty if needed. Let me know if the posted solution is what u are looking for?

Comment: Thanks guys I will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the requirement right, Try the following query which uses: [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)

**Input:**

```
[
  {
    "date": ISODate("2020-01-16T08:54:17.604Z")
  }
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      outputDate: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          "year": {
            $year: "$date"
          },
          "month": {
            $month: "$date"
          },
          "day": {
            $dayOfMonth: "$date"
          },
          "hour": {
            $hour: "$date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**O/P:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "outputDate": ISODate("2020-01-16T08:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

[Playground Test Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BiAeIbEBZCO)

Comment: your solution is great and easy but for some reason my query looses its grouping. have a look in Mongo playground. https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZjgAovr_fCB

Comment: Please try this link, ignore last one. https://mongoplayground.net/p/buULxJciaGY

Answer (score 1):

I think following query will solve your problem because MongoDB 3.6 supports *dateFromString*

Input:

```
[
  {
    "dateS": "2020-01-16T08"
  }
]
```

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "year": {"$substr": ["$dateS",0,4]},
      "month": {"$substr": ["$dateS",5,2]},
      "day": {"$substr": ["$dateS",8,2]},
      "hour": {"$substr": ["$dateS",11,2]}
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "isoString": {
        "$concat": ["$year","-","$month","-","$day","T","$hour",":00:00Z"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "newDate": {
        $dateFromString: {"dateString": "$isoString"}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "day": "16",
    "hour": "08",
    "isoString": "2020-01-16T08:00:00Z",
    "month": "01",
    "newDate": ISODate("2020-01-16T08:00:00Z"),
    "year": "2020"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I used combined solution from @ambienBeing and @techstack. Thanks

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aUBwxfZO_Qm)

```
  "parsedDate": {
          "$dateFromParts": {
            "year": {
              "$year": {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: {
                    "$concat": [
                      "$_id.dateHour",
                      ":00:00Z"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "month": {
              "$month": {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: {
                    "$concat": [
                      "$_id.dateHour",
                      ":00:00Z"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "day": {
              "$dayOfMonth": {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: {
                    "$concat": [
                      "$_id.dateHour",
                      ":00:00Z"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "hour": {
              "$hour": {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: {
                    "$concat": [
                      "$_id.dateHour",
                      ":00:00Z"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
```